# Writing XML metadata with Python?

Tags: raster, python-2.7, xml, metadata, iso-19115

Some Python software I have written generates raster files via GDAL. I would like the software to create an XML metadata file for each raster so that I can include details about how the raster was made, who made it, and so-on.

I understand that ISO 19115 is the international geospatial metadata standard. I really have no idea where to start with generating a metadata file, though. Can GDAL do this from scratch? Or would it be better to work with a dedicated XML library in Python?

Comment: If you decide to go with a python library, I can definitely recommend lxml. I find it very easy to use and the Xpath functionality is great. http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

THis post got me started to create a needed XML-file with Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python

in my case, this code:

```
##############################
#Create the necessary XML file
##############################
root = ET.Element("OGRVRTDataSource")
OGRVRTLayer  = ET.SubElement(root, "OGRVRTLayer")
OGRVRTLayer.set("name", AMSRcsv_shortname)

SrcDataSource = ET.SubElement(OGRVRTLayer, "SrcDataSource")
SrcDataSource.text = AMSRcsv

GeometryType = ET.SubElement(OGRVRTLayer, "GeometryType")
GeometryType.text = "wkbPoint"

GeometryField = ET.SubElement(OGRVRTLayer,"GeometryField")
GeometryField.set("encoding", "PointFromColumns")
GeometryField.set("x", "lon")
GeometryField.set("y", "lat")
GeometryField.set("z", "brightness")

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(AMSRcsv_vrt)
```

creates such files:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
   <OGRVRTLayer name="GW1AM2_201301010834_032D_L1SGRTBR_1110110_channel89H">
      <SrcDataSource>G:\AMSR\GW1AM2_201301010834_032D_L1SGRTBR_1110110_channel89H.csv</SrcDataSource>
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat" z="brightness" />
   </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```